# raise application error Trigger in MySQL DBMS

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am dealing with triggers in MySQL, and I want to add the raise application error, but my code indicates :

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(-20000,'Pay is below Texas minimum wage!');
>
> END IF;
>
> END' at line 9

and if I remove the part of raise application error, it works perfectly .

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS gmtt.after_update_mcorr @@

CREATE TRIGGER gmtt.after_update_mcorr
AFTER UPDATE ON gmtt.mcorr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       IF OLD.etat = '0' AND NEW.etat = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO historique(message, User, dateHisto) VALUES (CONCAT( 'a achevé la Maintenance ', OLD.codeMaint) , CURRENT_USER(), NOW()); 
       ELSE
raise_application_error(-20000,'Pay is below Texas minimum wage!');     

    END IF;

    END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax appears to be MySQL.  And yet, `raise_application_error` is an Oracle construct.  You want `signal`, documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html):

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS gmtt.after_update_mcorr @@
CREATE TRIGGER gmtt.after_update_mcorr
AFTER UPDATE ON gmtt.mcorr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.etat = '0' AND NEW.etat = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO historique(message, User, dateHisto)
             VALUES (CONCAT( 'a achevé la Maintenance ', OLD.codeMaint) , CURRENT_USER(), NOW()); 
   ELSE
       signal sqlstate '-20000' set message_text = 'Pay is below Texas minimum wage!';     
   END IF;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```