# trigger on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this message when i try to execute this code:

## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de '(-20512, 'stock insuffisant')' à la ligne 5

```
CREATE TRIGGER `verifier_stockmin` BEFORE INSERT ON `produits`
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.Stock-new.StockMin < 100 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20512, 'stock insuffisant');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

`raise_application_error` is an Oracle construct. You want `signal`

[raise application error Trigger in MySQL DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611802/raise-application-error-trigger-in-mysql-dbms)